# C# Error In Console

Tags: c#, console

I have a source for a game I play. The console throws an error once I log in the game. Here is the error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: count
   at System.String.RemoveInternal(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
   at ConquerServer.Extra.ItemIDManipulation.ChangeDigit(Byte Place, Byte To) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ConquerServer\ConquerServer\Extra.cs:line 134
   at ConquerServer.Extra.ItemIDManipulation.ToComposeID(Byte EqPos) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ConquerServer\ConquerServer\Extra.cs:line 235
   at ConquerServer.Entities.Character.EqpStats(Byte Pos, Boolean Equip) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ConquerServer\ConquerServer\Entities\Character.cs:line 1361
   at ConquerServer.Entities.Character.SendExtra() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ConquerServer\ConquerServer\Entities\Character.cs:line 1637
```

Here are the codes:

```
public void ChangeDigit(byte Place, byte To)
            {
                string Item = Convert.ToString(ID);
                string N = Item.Remove(Place - 1, Item.Length - Place + 1) + To.ToString();
                N += Item.Remove(0, Place);
                ID = uint.Parse(N);
            }


if (EqPos == 1 || EqPos == 3)
                {
                    ChangeDigit(4, 0);
                    ChangeDigit(6, 0);
                }

Extra.ItemIDManipulation e = new Extra.ItemIDManipulation(Equipment[Pos].ID);
                uint PID = e.ToComposeID(Pos);


if (Equipment[i].ID != 0)
                    {
                        MyClient.SendData(Packets.AddItem(Equipment[i], i));
                        EqpStats(i, true);
                    }
```

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please, please, please, make an effort to format your code properly. There is special code formatting available. (The `{}` button).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this method instead.

```
   public void ChangeDigit(byte Place, byte To) 
   { 
       string Item = Convert.ToString(ID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       if(Place > Item.Length || Place < 1)
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Place");

       Item = Item.Remove(Place-1) + To.ToString() + Item.Substring(Place)
       ID = uint.Parse(Item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
```

If it throws an exception it means the ID is wrong/empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check if **Item.Length - Place + 1** is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because when you make the following call:

```
ChangeDigit(4, 0);
```

The value of `ID` cannot be less than 3 characters in length.

For example, say `ID = "AB"`, when you then call `Item.Remove(Place - 1, Item.Length - Place + 1)` within the call to `ChangeDigit(4, 0)` it will essentially be doing this:

```
int startIndex = 4 - 1 // 3
int count = 2 - 4 + 1 // -1
"AB".Remove(startIndex, count)
```

As you can see here, the `count` argument is `-1` which would result in the exception you are getting `Count cannot be less than zero`.

You need to bring your program up in the debugger and take a look at what the ID value is at the time the exception is being thrown. Perhaps the ID is an empty string, or not what your expecting it to be because of a bug somewhere else in your code?